# How can I set MYSQL_PS1 in Mysql docker container

Tags: mysql, docker, dockerfile

I have three replicated mysql nodes with group replication.

When I  started them, they have the same prompt ( mysql> ) . I want to different prompts for all of them

Comment: That variable is a property of the [`mysql` command-line client tool](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-commands.html), not the server; why do you want to set that variable on the server container?

Comment: edited @DavidMaze

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`docker exec` has a `-e` option that can specify environment variable.

```
$ docker exec -e ROOT='r $ ' -it amazing_diffie bash
root@b4bedf563797:/# echo $ROOT
r $
```

You can also specify the environment variable when the container is created

```
$ docker run -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=bob \
             -e MYSQL_PS1='r $' \
             --name node1  mysql:8.0
```

Then is already in the container:

```
$ docker exec  -it node1 bash
root@a3e6e65f2b89:/# env
MYSQL_MAJOR=8.0
HOSTNAME=a3e6e65f2b89
PWD=/
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=bob
HOME=/root
MYSQL_VERSION=8.0.19-1debian10
GOSU_VERSION=1.12
TERM=xterm
MYSQL_PS1=r $
SHLVL=1
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I  specified the environment variable  -e  MYSQL_PS1='\u@containername[\d]> ' and its worked